# Countif over n>1 range

Tags: excel, countif

I have the following formula:

```
=countifs(G:G;"apple";H:J;"banana")
```

The idea is that column `G` either contains "apple" or not but "banana" can be in any of the columns `H, I, J`. I want to count the columns where "apple" is in `G` and "banana" in either `H`, `I`or `J`. Sometimes that range can be greater (e.g. `H:L`) but "banana" will appear at most once per row.

The formula above returns a `#VALUE` error. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Couple options, depending on how complicated you want to get. String 3 Countifs together: `=countifs(G:G;"apple";H:H;"banana")+countifs(G:G;"apple",I:I;"banana")...` or use `SUMPRODUCT` or maybe one of the approaches outlined [here](https://excelxor.com/2015/03/30/counting-rows-where-at-least-one-condition-is-met/).

Answer (score 0):

The ranges for COUNTIFS must all be the same size/shape. You can use SUMPRODUCT instead, but don't use entire column references:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G1:G1000="apple")*(H1:J1000="banana"))
```

or add multiple COUNTIFS formulas.

Comment: is this an ```OR```or ```AND``` statement? As in, will it count only rows that satisfy both conditions or rows that satisfy at least one?

Comment: The best solution I found now is to concatenate all columns that may potentially contain "banana" in one consolidated column and use wildcards in the countifs.... It's not really the answer to my question but it works.

Comment: It's an AND condition. For OR, you'd use `+` rather than `*`